# Does execve() make a child unrelated to its parent?

Tags: process, exec, ipc

When a process fork() a child, the two processes are related. The child inherits a lot of things from the parent, including some IPC objects such as pipes and anonymous   memory mappings.

If the child execve() an executable, do the parent and child processes become unrelated? Do things that work only for related processes  no longer work?

For example, is it correct that

- a shell process fork() a child to execve() an executable?
- The shell process and its child can't communicate via IPC mechanisms for related processes only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`execve()` completely replaces memory.

It closes those file handles that are not marked to be kept open.  (Usually, STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR are so marked.)  See flag `O_CLOEXEC`.  (OK, more correctly, it closes those file descriptors marked to be closed.)

It resets signal handlers, but keeps SIG_IGN and SIG_DFL as is.

It does not change the parent/child relationship, or the controlling terminal.

I'm not sure about SysV IPC objects, but I think they have no particular in-process existence to begin with.

Comment: Thanks. What is " they have no particular in-process existence to begin with."? Are the two processes still related, and do  things such as pipes and anonymous memory mappings that work only for related processes still work?

Comment: A SysV semaphore, as obtained by `semget()` is an integer.  It is a number in a global pool of semaphores.  You manipulate the global object.  If you know the number (and have permissions), you can manipulate it.  So a semaphore number could be passed over `execve()` in an argument or environment, and just used.  (In Linux, these are optional to begin with.  They aren't widely used.)

Comment: There are also SysV message queues (`msgget()`, etc...) that I believe used the same model.  There is also a shared memory object (`shmget()`, etc, I think), but that's covered as memory.

Comment: Anonymous memory is memory.  It is replaced.   Pipes are file descriptors, and can be retained.